# Moderator Position Open - Nominations Needed

Tags: discussion, moderation

We are looking to fill an available moderator position here on History SE and are looking for interested users.

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing two extra provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active on the site
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://history.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://history.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Oooh...nifty! I didn't know this could/would be done for a beta site. I believe all our previous mods were silently appointed.

Comment: We need 3, right? So I've nominated 3 more in addition to Mark Wallace. I've made them community wikis so that others can add. Unfortunately, I can't vote on my own posts!

Comment: @axsvl77 We have two positions open, to replace two inactive mods. It's just better (and easier) to ask who's interested than go searching for replacements in secret.

Comment: @animuson I've nominated some. If you don't like them, that's fine. And above it says "3" not "2", so I assume TED has to be re-nominated.

Comment: @axsvl77 Ah that was just a copy-paste error. TED doesn't need renominated. :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: One important stat a lot of people overlook is timezone base. When last we had three active mods, all three were based in the USA Central timezone. While we mods are human and have to sleep, the international Nazi/troll conspiracy to destroy the internet merrily works 24/7.

Comment: One note for expert users. On a graduated site, I believe there would be another round where people actually vote. That other round would have "candidate scores" attached to all the entries. If you are curious, (and a wee bit computer handy), you can [calculate candidate scores for users yourself using these instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289501/how-is-candidate-score-calculated). As a hint, I will tell you that out of the 4 entries so far, my score comes in 3rd. :-)

Comment: So any hint on *when* selections will take place? (or did I miss that part somewhere?)

Comment: @justCal I'm in the process of contacting people / waiting for responses. Will post another announcement when everything is finalized.

Answer (score 22):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I hesitate to do this, but I would like to offer myself for consideration because I'm in the UTC + 8 time zone. It's pretty much the exact opposite of the American ones, so I'm usually active precisely while the mods are asleep.

While I did only recently return from a prolonged break from SE, the circumstances behind that are no longer in effect.

Comment: +1 I'm glad you're back. I very much enjoy reading your contributions to this site.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I nominate Mark C. Wallace. In my time here this user stands out as someone who regularly encourages higher qualify questions and answers through his helpful comments, edits, and flagging. Mark has also been prolific in reviewing posts and voting on closing, opening, and deletes, not to mention being a consistent and regular user. I believe this nominee would be a good choice for moderator because of these qualities.

I accept the nomination (with some trepidation)

I'm East Coast timezone, with limited access (phone only; no keyboard) during the day. I've got to get to work now, but I'll try to write more later - questions welcome.

Comment: I'm more than happy to second that nomination.

Comment: I think this is the obvious choice.

Comment: Definitely the one I'd nominate too.

Comment: Honestly, I'd be more worried about someone who accepted with no trepidation whatsoever.

Comment: A good candidate and one I'd be happy to support.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because …

He's been doing a good job for more than a couple years. Very level headed, and deserves to continue.

Comment: Turns out that according to SE employee, TED will continue in his role. Still, I appreciate TED's work around here, so I'll leave this up.

Comment: I do appreciate it. Yes, I still intend to keep going. My goal is to help get this site to graduation, and then hand in my diamond and go back to being a normal user.

Comment: @T.E.D. It would be a shame if you quit, you're doing a stellar job!

Answer (score 16):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because …

Although a new user, sempaiscuaba brings professionalism and a strong time commitment to the table. In the time he has been contributing, he has been quickly become and important contributor by answering questions and by improving site operation.

---

I'll be honest here. My first reaction upon seeing my name here was to echo William Tecumsah Sherman's response when he was asked about the 1884 Presidential election!

I am honoured (and not a little surprised) to have been nominated. However, I do worry that my appointment would have a divisive, rather than a cohesive, effect on the community (I think the pattern of voting so far makes that point quite clear).

That said, the fact that I am in the UK (the [UT timezone](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEhelp/TimeZone.html)) would certainly help maintain a fast response to concerns flagged by the community, and help in the struggle against "*the international Nazi/troll conspiracy to destroy the internet*" mentioned by @T.E.D. in the comments above.

So, after giving the matter some considerable thought, and also with great trepidation, I accept the nomination.

So, here goes.

---

I accept this nomination

Hi, I am Iain and I live in the east end of London in dear old Blighty.

I'm fairly new to the Stack Exchange community, having been a member for just over six months. I still don't really get the idea of motivation by reputation scores and badges (which probably amounts to heresy on SE, I know!).

In that time, I've been fairly active on the site, both in terms of answering questions and carrying out the site self-moderation tasks from the Review queues. I do feel quite strongly that we are often not sufficiently supportive towards new users of the site. This is something which I have tried to argue for on meta in the past, and something that I will continue to argue for in the future - irrespective of whether I am appointed as a moderator.

If this site is to grow to maturity, then we need new users, and those users will often need a little extra support to get used to the rules of the community.

Beyond that, there is a little more background about me in my [profile bio](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/24858/). If anyone would like to know more, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Another strong candidate. His contribution in answering questions is second to none I think, and his answers are always with sources. Very professional, and I think his being in a different time zone is useful.

Comment: I would strongly support this nomination. He is very professional, and his support of new users is highly impressive. An excellent candidate.

Comment: um why is this CW?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος That's just how it was originally posted. Like a couple of the other nominations. :)

Comment: @sempaiscuba no, I asked why it was posted like this and the other two ones by the same user.

Comment: I posted it and switched it to community because I was hoping that other individuals would edit the nomination to include more relevant material. Not sure why I thought that.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Why do you care?

Comment: @axsvl77 Because it's a bit difficult to see the nominator without going to the revision history. Also, suggested edits by the nominees will most probably be accepted.

Comment: I thought he already was a mod.  I support bringing reality in line with my perception. <Grin>

Answer (score 12):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because …

He is a long term user who maintains an active role in the website. Very professional, courteous, and respectful.

Comment: Has a good record with asking questions too (asking questions is an underrated contribution).

Answer (score 4):

I am writing to announce my "non-candidacy,"--and to endorse two others; Semaphore and Sempaiscuba, who have already been nominated. Under other circumstances, I might have "stood up" for the vacant positions, but have elected to "stand down" in favor of the other two.

Apart from having high reputations comparable to mine, these two individuals bring important qualities to the table that I don't. The first has already been mentioned; Semaphore is based in Tokyo, and Sempaiscuba in London, which is to say, in two very different time zones than our American moderator T.E.D. In fact, the three of them would cover the globe roughly one-third, one-third, one-third of a world apart.

The second set of qualities stems from the first. Semaphore is Asian, and Sempaiscuba is European, and again, those perspectives complement our American moderator.

The community would be fortunate to have a geographically and culturally balanced team of these three people.

Comment: The points made by Tom Au are well stated. Time zone is important, but having a US / European / Asian 'team' perhaps even more so.

Comment: @LarsBosteen - Call it moral cowardice, but I take the geography/troll angle more because its inarguable, and gets us the diversity for free, so I don't have to publicly open that possible can of worms. Unfortunately, that doesn't get us gender diversity...

Comment: @T.E.D.: "That doesn't get us gender diversity" because there are so few women on the site. The highest ranking one that I know for sure is a woman is the Honorable Rose.

Comment: Exactly. We may have more than we think due to (probably purposely picked) gender neutral names, but you are otherwise quite right about the lack. Believe me, if I had a good idea for how to fix it, I'd be all over it.

Comment: @T.E.D.: To take one example, I don't know if "Semaphore" is a man or a woman. Neither the name nor the cat photo is definitive. Maybe you or someone else has greater knowledge regarding this.

Answer (score -5):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I am new to this site and would like to nominate myself. I have been a daily contributor for a short time now but am a top 2% contributor this quarter. I think it would be helpful to have the perspective of a  new recruit, not committed to any of the existing processes.  Bring a different perspective from an estate underrepresented in the august more established members already nominated.

Comment: What "existing processes" are you referring to? Each individual moderator has some responsibilities, and for beta sites mods also strive for graduation. What process would you do others won't?

Comment: I think it's ridiculous how many good questions are closed on purely subjective grounds.  I think its ridiculous that the fig leaf being put forward for such actions is to protect the quality of the website.   I think it holds us back.  As moderator I would work to stop this and facilitate broad respectful discussions across any historic topic.  I would also advise not rewarding people who participate in pedantic disruptive behavior with badges or rewards which don't defend excellence but upend the participation and enjoyment of the site.

Comment: One thing I found as a moderator (quite to my surprise) is I actually in a lot of ways have *less* influence over question closure than I did as a user. Mod closures aren't votes, they *just happen*. As a result of that, I really can't participate in closure / reopen votes like I did as a user.