# Welcome to our new pro tem moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Thanks to everyone who participated in the [recent nominations](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3589/moderator-position-open-nominations-needed) to select new moderators. We're always happy to see the community being proactive and getting involved in who is leading their site. Now, I'm happy to announce that your site has three new pro tem moderators who have stepped up and volunteered their time to help lead this site to success. Here they are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'd also like to thank two of our past moderators for everything they've done for this site up until this point. Their moderator status is being removed at this time as well:

[image]

[image]

Good luck to the new moderators, and good luck to the site as a whole!

Comment: I think having 4 mods was the right decision.

Comment: I would like to thank all those who volunteered or agreed to act as Moderators, you are all great assets to this site!

Answer (score 2):

Given that beta sites don't have moderator elections or terms, I welcome our new dictators (in the [Roman sense of the word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_dictator))!

May your terms be more like humble Cincinnatus and less like power-hungry Julius Caesar. We don't want any moderators becoming emperors!